# Problems about placeholders of Netlify redirects

Tags: url-rewriting, pattern-matching, redirect, netlify

I am trying to set up some URL rewrites in Netlify.

I want to set up a rewrite to redirect

```
https://example.com/blog/2019/05/15/hello.html
```

to

```
https://example.com/blog/2019/05/hello.html
```

I read the document - https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#placeholders:

> You can use placeholders in the origin and target paths:
>
> ```
> /news/:year/:month/:date/:slug  /blog/:year/:month/:date/:slug
> ```
>
> This would redirect a URL like `/news/2004/02/12/my-story` to `/blog/2004/02/12/my-story`

And I have my `_redirects` file like this:

```
# Redirect old permalinks to new format
/blog/:year/:month/:date/:slug.html /blog/:year/:month/:slug.html 301!
```

It did work to redirect

```
https://example.com/blog/2019/05/15/hello.html
```

to

```
https://example.com/blog/2019/05/hello.html
```

But there is a weird problem, it also redirects

```
https://example.com/blog/2019/05/not-a-date/index.html
```

to

```
https://example.com/blog/2019/05/index.html
```

My question is, Is it able to (if yes, how can I) make the `:date` placeholder matching **day** only? `not-a-date` is not a date obviously, shouldn't `:date` match `01` to `31` only?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge the placeholders aren't typed (allowing only numbers). So anything will match and it's not possible to define only days as a pattern to match.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.healingislands.com/* http://www.healingisland.com:splat 301!
```

putting { /* } this at the end of the first link and putting { :splat 301! } this at the end just worked for me